# After clean project, FirebaseAnalytics causes a crash for ClassNotFoundException

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android, firebase-analytics

Since yesterday I am in trouble fixing this mistake. This error I started to find after a "clean" failed, because of the "freezing" of Visual Studio I was forced to stop the process.
This is the error stack:

```
11-14 10:57:30.210 I/mono-stdout(20645): Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics ---> Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.myappname.packagename-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.myappname.packagename-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.myappname.packagename-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics ---> Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.myappname.packagename-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.myappname.packagename-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.myappname.packagename-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
11-14 10:57:30.217 I/mono-stdout(20645):    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
11-14 10:57:30.217 I/mono-stdout(20645):   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:151 
11-14 10:57:30.218 I/mono-stdout(20645):   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+StaticMethods.CallStaticObjectMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00069] in <ea989c10241f4c8a9adb15ef93d69358>:0 
11-14 10:57:30.218 I/mono-stdout(20645):   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallStaticObjectMethod (System.IntPtr jclass, System.IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue* parms) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4986/fb018c56/source/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:562 
11-14 10:57:30.218 I/mono-stdout(20645):   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallStaticObjectMethod (System.IntPtr jclass, System.IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue[] parms) [0x00017] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4986/fb018c56/source/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:568 
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:151 
  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+StaticMethods.CallStaticObjectMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00069] in <ea989c10241f4c8a9adb15ef93d69358>:0 
  at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallStaticObjectMethod (System.IntPtr jclass, System.IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue* parms) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4986/fb018c56/source/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:562 
  at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallStaticObjectMethod (System.IntPtr jclass, System.IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue[] parms) [0x00017] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4986/fb018c56/source/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:568 
  at Android.Runtime.J
NIEnv.FindClass (System.String classname) [0x00007] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4986/fb018c56/source/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNIEnv.cs:602 
11-14 10:57:30.219 I/mono-stdout(20645):   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.FindClass (System.String classname) [0x00007] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4986/fb018c56/source/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNIEnv.cs:602 
11-14 10:57:30.219 I/mono-stdout(20645):   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.FindClass (System.String className, System.IntPtr& cachedJniClassHandle) [0x00011] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4986/fb018c56/source/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNIEnv.cs:616 
11-14 10:57:30.219 I/mono-stdout(20645):   at Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalytics.get_class_ref () [0x00000] in <0d9bc83400c247fbb8133267b3bc506d>:0 
11-14 10:57:30.220 I/mono-stdout(20645):   at Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalytics.GetInstance (Android.Content.Context context) [0x00014] in <0d9bc83400c247fbb8133267b3bc506d>:0 
11-14 10:57:30.220 I/mono-stdout(20645):   at com.meba.ui.EXAApplication.InitializeEXAApplication (com.meba.ui.android.controls.EXAActivity MainActivity) [0x00022] in C:\Progetti\com.meba\com.meba.ui.android\controls\EXAApplication.cs:677 
11-14 10:57:30.220 I/mono-stdout(20645):   --- End of managed Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException stack trace ---
  at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.FindClass (System.String className, System.IntPtr& cachedJniClassHandle) [0x00011] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4986/fb018c56/source/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNIEnv.cs:616 
  at Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalytics.get_class_ref () [0x00000] in <0d9bc83400c247fbb8133267b3bc506d>:0 
  at Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalytics.GetInstance (Android.Content.Context context) [0x00014] in <0d9bc83400c247fbb8133267b3bc506d>:0 
  at com.meba.ui.EXAApplication.InitializeEXAApplication (com.meba.ui.android.controls.EXAActivity MainActivity) [0x00022] in C:\Progetti\com.meba\com.meba.ui.android\controls\EXAApplication.cs:677 
  --- End of managed Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException stack trace ---
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics
11-14 10:57:30.220 I/mono-stdout(20645): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics
11-14 10:57:30.221 I/mono-stdout(20645):    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
11-14 10:57:30.221 I/mono-stdout(20645):    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)
    at md5a8add535933d47bad1d9f0eed06bba35.MainActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
    at md5a8add535933d47bad1d9f0eed06bba35.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6301)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2654)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
11-14 10:57:30.221 I/mono-stdout(20645):    at md5a8add535933d47bad1d9f0eed06bba35.MainActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
11-14 10:57:30.222 I/mono-stdout(20645):    at md5a8add535933d47bad1d9f0eed06bba35.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
11-14 10:57:30.222 I/mono-stdout(20645):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6301)
11-14 10:57:30.222 I/mono-stdout(20645):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113)
11-14 10:57:30.222 I/mono-stdout(20645):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519)
11-14 10:57:30.222 I/mono-stdout(20645):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2654)
11-14 10:57:30.222 I/mono-stdout(20645):    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
11-14 10:57:30.223 I/mono-stdout(20645):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1488)
11-14 10:57:30.223 I/mono-stdout(20645):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
11-14 10:57:30.223 I/mono-stdout(20645):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
11-14 10:57:30.223 I/mono-stdout(20645):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
11-14 10:57:30.223 I/mono-stdout(20645):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-14 10:57:30.223 I/mono-stdout(20645):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
11-14 10:57:30.223 I/mono-stdout(20645):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
11-14 10:57:30.224 I/mono-stdout(20645): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.myappname.packagename-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.myappname.packagename-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.myappname.packagename-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
11-14 10:57:30.224 I/mono-stdout(20645):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
11-14 10:57:30.224 I/mono-stdout(20645):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
11-14 10:57:30.224 I/mono-stdout(20645):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
11-14 10:57:30.224 I/mono-stdout(20645):    ... 16 more
11-14 10:57:30.224 I/mono-stdout(20645):    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.myappname.packagename-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.myappname.packagename-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.myappname.packagename-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
    ... 16 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        a
t java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
        ... 17 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
11-14 10:57:30.224 I/mono-stdout(20645):        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
11-14 10:57:30.224 I/mono-stdout(20645):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
11-14 10:57:30.225 I/mono-stdout(20645):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
11-14 10:57:30.225 I/mono-stdout(20645):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
11-14 10:57:30.225 I/mono-stdout(20645):        ... 17 more
11-14 10:57:30.225 I/mono-stdout(20645):    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

I have try to re-clean, rebuild, build, check references (all ok), try on different device (Huawei Android 7.0, thl Android 6.0), update SDK and company from Android SDK Manager, update Xamarin and VS[image].
I tried to move everything through SVN on another machine, but the problem was also found on the other.

Any idea or help?

> I replaced my package name in output with a fake.
>
> Before I found the error I updated the device OS (Huawei P9), but the error is also found on a THL with different OS

Comment: Try disable the `Use Fast Deployment` in `Android Options`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days with the same problem I understand this:

If you has downloaded Library from Nuget you need to be sure about some points:

1) XAMARIN.DOWNLOAD.BUILD
Updating from Android SDK Manager is unusefull for Xamarin Binders, this because VS use (I suppose) Xamarin.Download.Build to align jar during compiling process. This is the reason you always need to include this components in projects (if you use some Xamarin Binders).

To check if you have downloaded all jars and to understand wich components are miss, browse the folder **library_projects**\ in obj folder.
If is all OK you will find classes.jar

Don't mantain this folder manually because any CLEAN operation delete the content of the folder.

2) ALIGN VERSIONS DEPENDENCIES
All Google libraries are part of the same "Service package"
If you use different google services (firebase, maps, cloud platform)
be sure that al components you use are at same version and that components have the same dependencies, if not align components. If you don't repair this you problably encour in strange compiling error about missing methods in jar file. I'll suppose this happen because the libraries have the same dependency but in different versions.

3) ALWAYS USE NUGET
Use always NUGET for add/remove componnents. When I manually referenced different version of components previously downloaded with NUGET for solving the same problem, I continuosly had compiling error. This is caused because if you refer library manually (and remove manually the previous reference) in you project file (.prj) remains "Import instructions" of wrong reference.

4) CHECK COMPILING OUTPUT
If you dont understand the compiling error. Check the Full detailed log of compiling process (You can set it in VS Options). Usually One strange error depend by previous warning not listed in default output mode.